# Android SQLite: Error creating second table in second Activity

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-activity

I'm facing the current problem:

I have an application with a first Activity `MainActivity` and a second Activity called `SecondActivity`.
Now, in both of these I need a separate table:

This is my HelperClass:

```
public class FMSDatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String FMS_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE fms (fmsId integer primary key autoincrement, status TEXT, date TEXT, kennung TEXT);";
    private static final String ZVEI_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE zvei (zveiId integer primary key autoincrement, schleife TEXT, date TEXT, description TEXT);";

    public static final String TABLE_FMS = "fms";
    public static final String TABLE_ZVEI = "zvei";

    public static final String COLUMN_FMS_ID = "fmsId";
    public static final String COLUMN_FMS_KENNUNG = "kennung";
    public static final String COLUMN_FMS_STATUS = "status";
    public static final String COLUMN_FMS_DATE = "date";

    public static final String COLUMN_ZVEI_ID = "zveiId";
    public static final String COLUMN_ZVEI_SCHLEIFE = "schleife";
    public static final String COLUMN_ZVEI_DATE = "date";
    public static final String COLUMN_ZVEI_DESCRIPTION = "description";

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public FMSDatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, "fms.db", null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(FMS_TABLE_CREATE + ZVEI_TABLE_CREATE);
            //db.execSQL(FMS_TABLE_CREATE);
            //db.execSQL(ZVEI_TABLE_CREATE);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_FMS);
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ZVEI);

      onCreate(db);
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public List<ZVEI> getAllZvei() {

        List<ZVEI> zveiList = new ArrayList<ZVEI>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ZVEI + " ORDER BY zveiId DESC";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ZVEI zvei = new ZVEI();
                zvei.setZveiId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                zvei.setSchleife(cursor.getString(1));
                zvei.setDate(cursor.getString(2));
                zvei.setDescription(cursor.getString(3));
                zveiList.add(zvei);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return zveiList;

    }

}
```

When the `MainActivity` starts, the `getAllZvei()` method ist called, so in my opinion, the `onCreate()` method (via the `db.getWritableDatabase()`) from the HelperClass should be also called. 
Mysterious: the table `zvei` is created, but NOT the `fms`. So when I start my second activity (which calls another method, `getAllFms()`, similar to `getAllZvei()`, just removed it in this source here), it crashes and LogCat tells me:

```
noch such table: fms
```

I run this on a Nexus 4 emulator. Wiped the user data, cleared data from the app and uninstalled the app. I pulled the `fms.db` via DDMS and viewed in SQLiteBrowser, but only zvei is present.

I can't explain why. Can you?

**UPDATE**
I just renamed the database name and recognized in DDMS, that still the old name was generated. So I just cleaned and rebuilt the project, deleted the emulator and created a new one, wiped the user data (yes, even if I just created it!) and now: **it works!**

Thanks to all of you!

Comment: Your Update was working for me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I see you're concatenating the two SQL statements instead of executing them separately:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        db.execSQL(FMS_TABLE_CREATE + ZVEI_TABLE_CREATE);
        //db.execSQL(FMS_TABLE_CREATE);
        //db.execSQL(ZVEI_TABLE_CREATE);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

That might be where your problem lies. Android SQLite doesn't much care for compound statements. Besides, the performance gain you think you're getting by concatenating is lost in the concatenating itself, and parsing the larger compound statement.

Comment: Yes, thought so, too. This is why there are (commented) two separate execute statements. But this also does not work :/

Comment: `execSQL()` executes a single SQL statement. You might have tried concatenated version first, hence `onCreate()` is not called in consecutive runs (after fix). Uninstall the app completely, split `execSQL()` statements and re-install.

Comment: @sebastian Try removing the try/catch and see what happens.

Comment: Nothing. Just the `zvei` table is created, not the `fms`. LogCat then sais: `no such table: fms`

Comment: @sebastian That is really strange. I tried the CREATE TABLE statement in an SQLite manager and it works just fine, so the problem's not there. I'm as stumped as you are.

Comment: meh, this is not what I wanted to hear ;) It's a really strange behaviour, because when I open the second activity, my app crashes.